# How to get all paths between to items

Tags: java, recursion

I have to compute all possible paths between two items from a list. Each item has two fields: its name and its neighbor's name.

I have to generate a list containing all items that would allow me to make a path between two particular items.

Imagine I have Item(A, B) and Item(A, C) and I am being asked for the solution from B to C. I have to return both Items as I can reach C from B by using both of them: B->A->C.

Note that I have no limit on the Items I need to reach a destination.

I have tried several solutions but none of them was successful. I know I have to use some kind of recursive function but I can't figure out how.

This is my Item class:

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private String neighbor;

    public Item(String name, String neighbor){

        this.name = name;
        this.neighbor = neighbor;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

As I have to obtain all possible paths between two particular items, I have to return a list of lists:

```
List<List<Item>> solution;
```

### My workaround

I finally converted my items to a Graph and, once it is build, I use Depth First Transversal (DFT) in order to find all possible paths between a source and a destination.

I set key-value pairs relating each Item's name with a graph representation and, from the Graph I get a list of Integers that indicates the path in the graph (1-2-3-5, for instance). From that list I find my Items and I return a list of lists with the format I've already explained.

Posting just for someone with a similar problem!

Comment: Why not use a different data structure (such as a directed or undirected graph) that better models the relationships between your nodes?

Comment: Because it is a requirement to work with this data structure

Comment: Ok, you could iterate over each node and perform a depth-first search on each node to see if you can reach the desired node (marking nodes along the way as visited to avoid cycles).

Comment: You talk about lists, but what you're describing is at the very least a tree, but even more likely an undirected graph. So: it sounds like you've been using entirely the wrong data structure and your problem would become so much easier by first making sure you're using the right data structure instead. Either write or use a simple graph data structure, with parent/child relations instead of "neighbours", and your search algorithm becomes "try to reach X from here, by contacting all parents and all children (with a `seen` list for nodes already contacted)".

Comment: Yes, I agree with you @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans . I am working with an undirected graph. My problem is that I have to use this data structure compulsory so I will try to create an undirected graph from my data and work with the graph

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this based on my comment:

> you could iterate over each node and perform a depth-first search on
>   each node to see if you can reach the desired node

You mark visited nodes both to avoid cycles (if they're even possible in your use-case) and to track the path.

```
List<Item> depthFirstSearch(Item startItem, Item desiredItem, List<Item> visitedNodes) {
    if (startItem.equals(desiredItem)) {
        return visitedNodes;
    }

     // Exit if we reach a cycle or no more neighbors to follow
    if (visitedNodes.contains(startItem) || startItem.getNeighbor() == null) {
        return null;
    }

    visitedNodes.add(startItem); 

     // Recurse; continue search from neighbor
    return depthFirstSearch(startItem.getNeighbor(), desiredItem, visitedNodes);
}
```

And use it like this (You'll need to adapt this to your code):

```
List<Item> items;
List<List<Item>> result = new List<List<Item>>();

for (Item item : items) {   
    List<Item> pathToDesired = depthFirstSearch(item, desiredItem, new LinkedList<Item>());

    if (pathToDesired != null) {
        results.add(pathToDesired);
    }
}
```

`result` will contain all paths to the desired item.

Comment: There is a problem in your solution and it is that the neighbor field of Item is a String, not a different Item. Each item has two fields, its name and its neighbor name. It represent the connection between two items rather than the items themselves.

Comment: Ah ok, so in that case I'd store your items in a hashmap using 'name' as the key. Rather than recursing on `startItem.getNeighbor()`, use `startItem.getNeighbor()` as the key to get the actual item from the hashmap and recurse on that: i.e.  `depthFirstSearch(itemMap.get(startItem.getNeighbor()), desiredItem, visitedNodes);`

Comment: Yes, it could work. Thanks so much for your time. What I finally did was convert my data to a Graph and, by using DFT as you suggested, I find all paths between a source and a destination in the graph.